# Can't install any update or software from Software Center

Tags: 11.10, apt, updates, software-center

I tried to install updates and it's saying to get partial upgrade
When trying Partial Upgrade doesn't working again.
And when trying to install any software it doesn't installing.
Can someone help me?

## EDIT

the `sudo apt-get update` output is

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) 
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/ E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) 
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: please provide output of this "sudo apt-get update"

Comment: that output is:                                                E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?